# Where to get software name of CLSID

Tags: windows

I'm in such a situation that every week I need to find one or two software *names* and all I know is CLSID. I want to ask if there is any official place where I could look for.

Comment: Are we talking about CLSIDs (for COM interfaces) or about GUIDs in general? Where did you get the CLSID from?

Comment: @ST3 - I know of no database that would hold this information.  I would use your current process.

Comment: @Werner I have some CLSIDs for COM interface. I have them from one registry cleaner.

Answer (score 14):

If you have a CLSID {xxx} you can take a look at the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{xxx}\`. The default value for the registry key will give you a description of the CLSID. Other values under the key will give you more information like the DLL that implements the interface and a short name (program ID).

There is an [article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265/COM-IDs-Registry-keys-in-a-nutshell) that gives you a good overview over the COM registry keys.